# How do I make a radio button value depend on a table row selected

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I have made a table which gets data from a mysql database and puts in into a html form. However, I have been trying to make buttons on each row which would then have a variable value equal two one of the values in the rows. Here is my code:

```
$html_table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><th>Company           Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    </th><th>Actual Stockprice&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Total     Value&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th> Sell? </th><tr>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {    
  $actstock = "\n".$json_output['l'];
  $company = $row['company'];
  $totalvalue = $row['amount']*$actstock;
  $radio="<input type='radio' value='$company' name='symbol' />";
  $dollar = "$";

 $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$row['company']. '</td><td>'    
.$row['amount'].'</td><td>'     
.$dollar.$actstock. '</td><td>' .$dollar.$totalvalue.'</td><td>' .$radio. '</td></tr>';
}
```

And then a button and then then

```
 $symbol = $_POST['symbol'];
echo $symbol;
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well it doesn't work and I'm not sure why

Comment: What doesn't work? What does it return now, and how is that different from what you expected?

Comment: The echo returns nothing, so the variable is basically empty. And I expected a string. (Which would be one of the columns in the table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think  your code is  good

**but did you put** $radio between `<form></form>` on that `<td>$radio</td>` ?

Comment: Hm... I've tried that but it didn't work yet. Thanks for the effort anyway!

Comment: Nevermind... I'm such an idiot! I put the button in a different form. Thank you!